# Not able to get Angular to work (even on git pages)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git

I am trying my first experiences with Angular, but I only get curly-braces for the angular expressions, even though the localhost server is running - it is the same on git pages..

Can anyone help me? Researching brings me more complex solutions such as stopping angluar displaying these braces on a more complex level, but I feel my question is very basic - but copying and testing as much as possible, I can't get it to work.

Below is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myFirstApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <title>Hello Coursera</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Coursera</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstController">
      {{$scope}}

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The app.js in the same folder:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myFirstApp', [])

  .controller('MyFirstController', funtion($scope) {
    $scope.name = "simon";
  });
})();
```

The angular.min.js file is located in the same folder and is downloaded directly.
Is this perhaps an old version or so?

Would really appreciate your help here.

Many thanks and best regards,
Simon

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you're starting with angular now - why not one of the later versions?

Comment: You need `{{name}}`, and in your app.js is a typo: `funtion` https://jsfiddle.net/btehd264/ (I recommend using an editor with code highlighting, my current favorite is VS Code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code. First of all you dont write {{$scope}} in html . You directly write variable name like `{{name}}`  then the function you spelled was wrong.
PFB the code and it will work for you.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myFirstApp', [])

  .controller('MyFirstController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "simon";
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="myFirstApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <title>Hello Coursera</title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <h1>Hello Coursera</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstController">
      {{name}}

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you both - a little more detailed reading would have helped - but honestly, I would never have found the variable one.. So thank you ever so much here - can now press on learning Angular